# Need to know client/user authentication solution

Tags: php, android, session, authentication, client-server

I have an API login for client(Mobile Apps), i want to know a solution if i'm using session login for mobile apps.

The flow would be like this, below:

> Client(Mobile Apps) -> Login(API) -> Generate Token and Save to Table
>   Token -> Success (Response Token)

Toke table would be like this, below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID | notoken                             | userid | created_at           |
|1; | "1d2c8ad6019b2ec31af909e7ac23ca1b"; |"3";    |"2015-06-11 17:25:24" |
|2; | "a1f6f81ff822a4be87b9e7c35d671ce9"; |"3";    |"2015-06-11 17:25:41" |
|3; | "57c99c22d884d5c3af1674ff9327926f"; |"3";    |"2015-06-11 18:24:23" |
|4; | "3c63d115ad798f2898deb838cdc2b447"; |"3";    |"2015-07-02 22:40:04" |
|5; | "c5b2bf2f957fdaa97e1abb79e164f23e"; |"3";    |"2015-07-02 22:40:43" |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When user login through API it will generate token like table above.

Solution Session Login:

If user doesnt have activity more than 5 hours, it will delete row that has same token in mobile apps. So i will create cronjob that will check the table who has no activity more than 5 hours and delete the row.

Question:

Is that solution above is good? or maybe there is other good solution?

> Already Login -> Check token is it has activity or not -> Yes -> Get
>   Information
>
> -if No-
>
> Pop up screen on the apps "session timeout or user has no activity"

Solution User Activity:

Every activty that the client do, it will update table token datetime. so if the client always has activy it will not delete or destroy `notoken` in Token table.

Question:

Is this solution will make the apps activity heavy load?

CMIIW